# Oracle ODP.net exception in asp.net on windows server 2012 standard R2

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odp.net, windows-server-2012-r2

I am getting the below exception while connecting to oracle database from asp.net application on .Net 4.5 and OS Windows Server 2012 Standard R2.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I already installed correct oracle 64 bit client and all things verified like environment variable paths,security and paths in registry.

Same thing working fine on windows 8 and windows 10.

It seems that windows server 2012 not detecting that oracle client was installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by using oracle client .exe setup instead of oracle client xcopy setup.